# Git Stash Apply on Master insted of Local branch

Tags: git, git-stash

I was on my local branch with current file changes and had to do a pull on Master.
So I did-

`git stash`
`git checkout master`
`git pull origin master`

At this step usually I do `git checkout myCurrentBranch`, and then `git stash apply stash@{0}`,
but due to oversight I did the apply stash on the Master branch itself.

How can I undo this step? And get back my file changes on myCurrentBranch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just do the following:

```
git stash
git checkout myCurrentBranch
git stash apply stash@{0}
```

This will return your changes to the stash and return the master branch to a clean state before switching back to your local branch and reapplying the stash there instead.

Comment: i did this verbatim before i saw this answer and works as expected. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since you used `git stash apply` rather than `git stash pop`, you *still have your saved stash*.  This means that you can wipe out the current changes with:

```
git reset --hard
```

followed by `git checkout` (or `git switch`) to your desired branch and another `git stash apply`.

#### Related, but nothing to do with `git stash`

You can save yourself a lot of effort in the future by *avoiding* `git pull`.  You do not need to update your `master` at this point, and in fact, you may be able to just *delete* your `master` branch entirely.  Instead of:

```
git stash
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout original-branch
git stash apply
# inspect and make sure all is well, and last:
git stash drop
```

you can use:

```
git fetch origin
# or just git fetch - "origin" is the usual default
```

When the `fetch` has finished, your `origin/master` is updated.  Instead of using your own `master`, you can now use your `origin/master`.  Note that `origin/master` is not a *branch* name: it's a *remote-tracking name* instead.  It remembers what your Git saw on the other Git over at `origin`, in *their* `master`, the last time you ran `git fetch origin` or `git fetch`.  Running `git fetch origin` updates your `origin/master` automatically, because it's your Git's memory of their branch: if they've updated their branch, your system updates and remembers this.  If they have not updated their branch, your system does not have to update anything, and doesn't.

Since you never need to navigate away from your current branch, you never have to use `git stash` either.

(If you want to *inspect* what came in, i.e., see what their `master`—your `origin/master`—looks like, there are various ways to do that, too, without disrupting your existing branch, but let's stop here since that wasn't your question.)

Comment: thanks for the deep dive!